# NoReverseMatch error using django with ajax

Tags: python, ajax, django

I am trying to add ajax on the delete button of my blog, I want to update the page without reloading it when I delete an article, but I am getting this error when I use ajax and I don't understand what's going wrong.

```
Reverse for 'article_effacer' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['article/delete/(?P<slug>[-\\w\\d]+)/$']
```

I am turning myself to you because I'm having a hard time resolving this issue, so here is the code.

**views.py**

```
def article_effacer(request, slug):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            user = request.user
            article = Article.objects.filter(slug=slug, user=user).delete()
            context = {'article':article}
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context), content_type='application/json')
        else:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^delete/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/$', views.article_effacer, name="article_effacer"),
```

**template.html**

```
<input class="delete" id="{{ a.slug }}"  data-url='{% url "article.views.article_effacer" a.slug %}' value="Effacer">
```

**Ajax**

```
    $('.delete').click(function(){
          var slug = $(this).attr('id');
          var url = $(this).data('url');
          $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: url,
                   data: {'slug': $(this).attr('id'), 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function(response) {
                          console.log('deleted')
                          $(".article" + slug).remove();
                    },
                   error: function(rs, e) {
                          console.log(slug)
                   }
              })
        })
```

The problems comes probably from the url, but I don't understand how to correct it, any suggestions?

**_ Update _**

**Full template**

```
{% block content %}

    {% for a in article %}
            <div class="article{{a.slug}}">
            [... unrelated html ...]
            {% if a.user == user %} |
                <input class="delete" id="{{ a.slug }}"  data-url='{% url "article.views.article_effacer" a.slug %}' value="Effacer">
            {% endif %}
            </div>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}

{% block javascript %}
    <script>
    $('.delete').click(function(){
          var slug = $(this).attr('id');
          var url = $(this).data('url');
          $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: url,
                   data: {'slug': $(this).attr('id'), 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function(response) {
                          console.log('deleted')
                          $(".article" + slug).remove();
                    },
                   error: function(rs, e) {
                          console.log(slug)
                   }
              })
        })
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use template tags like that, with values coming from JS; it should be clear that template tags are resolved on the server side, whereas the JS is executed on the client according to what the user clicks.

However you are halfway there by putting the value in the `input`. Actually, inputs don't have a `href` attribute, but you could use a `data-` prefix; the point is that you can then grab that in your JS to use as the URL. Something like:

```
<input class="delete" id="{{ a.slug }}" data-url='{% url "article.views.article_effacer" a.slug %}' value="Effacer">

var url = $(this).data('url');
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url,
     ...
});
```

Comment: Didn't see that I left the href on the input, I changed it and applied the change with the data prefix but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Well the point was to remove that logic from the JS, not just change the template. Did you do that too?

Comment: Do you have something called `a` in the context at that point? Maybe you should show the full template, and the view responsible for rendering it.